# Как в новом окне открыть Блокнот в windows 10 и 11?

Tags: windows-10, bat

Как из панели задач при каждом клике на иконку открыть в новом окне Блокнот в windows 10 и 11? Я пришёл к выводу, что нужно в свойствах ярлыка в поле "Объект" прописать какие-то параметры. Но нигде не нашёл никаких параметров под Блокнот. Или это как-то в bat файле прописывать можно?
[image: Свойства ярлыка Блокнота]

К примеру стоит иконка Блокнота в панели задач. Я на неё кликаю левой кнопкой мыши и открывается новое окно, кликаю ещё раз, открывается ещё одно новое окно. И чтобы оно не группировало окна, а открывало рядышком справа.

Comment: https://computerjet.ru/blog/windows/personalization/grouping-buttons-apps-taskbar/

Comment: Для windows 10 это подходит, чтобы отключить группировку окон. А в windows 11 такого нет. И ещё нужно, чтобы при каждом клике на иконку в панели задач справа открывалось новое окно программы.